# How are service.h files are generated from service.srv files?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Sevices in ROS, we create a service definition file in the `srv` folder and name it as `service.srv` and when we include this as `service.h` in the `cpp` file. How is the `.h` file generated from `.srv` ? In my case, while compiling using `catkin_make` it says no `service.h` file found in the `.cpp` file whereas it is present. Any leads ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290311/how-are-service.h-files-are-generated-from-service.srv-files-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> In my case, while compiling using `catkin_make` it says no `service.h` file found in the `.cpp` file whereas it is present. Any leads ?

you're running into a dependency declaration problem. We can explain to you how headers are generated from the IDL, but for this particular problem, see [C++ message or service dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html) in the Catkin documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-03**:
I took [this](https://github.com/fairlight1337/ros_service_examples) example from github and i guess it already has all the dependencies. @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-03**:
@gvdhoorn : yes, you were correct : fixed it by adding dependencies.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-04**:\

> I took [this](https://github.com/fairlight1337/ros_service_examples) example from github and i guess it already has all the dependencies. @gvdhoorn

well, I just checked it, and it doesn't (as you probably also found out).

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-04**:
yes : dependencies added !

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-15**:
@gvdhoorn again coming back to my previous question, how are headers generated from IDL ? For example, if i need to create a new service file, then how can I add the header file in the cpp. Normally it says no such file found.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:\

> Normally it says no such file found.

it should only give that error if you've not followed procedure.

provided the msg / srv file exists, you've added the dependencies to your target *and* followed the docs on generating msgs / srvs things should work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
It's all documented in the Catkin documentation I linked earlier and on the ROS wiki.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-15**:
I created an overlay space and copied the demo_nodes_cpp example in ROS2 into the overlay ws and renamed it(`heatflow_cpp`). Created a new service file(`heatFlow.srv`) and changed the name of the service file in the CMAKELISTS and then included `heatFlow.hpp` in the cpp.Am i forgetting something ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
You now mention ROS2, while you tagged your original question with `ROS` and `kinetic`. My answer detailed the situation in ROS1.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-15**:
sorry for the confusion, the entire question before the last comments was for ROS1. I was trying the same thing with ROS2 so that is why posted here in continuation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
Continuing a question after it has been answered is typically not the best way to ask new questions (which this basically is).

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-15**:
Sorry for the confusion. I posted a new question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/291210/how-is-the-servicehpp-file-generated-from-servicesrv-file-in-ros2/)